# Glottal stops that aren't tenuis

Tags: phonology, phonemes, glottal-stop

Is any language known to contain a glottal stop [ʔ] that isn't tenuis? For example, an aspirated glottal stop [ʔʰ], a palatalized glottal stop [ʔʲ], or a labialized glottal stop [ʔʷ].

CORRECTION: It turns out that tenuis is not the right word here. I mean glottal stops with a secondary feature, such as a aspiration or labialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aspirated glottal stop would be a fundamental contradiction (the vocal folds would have to be both spread apart and constricted). "Tenuis" does not preclude having secondary articulation, so [ʔʷ] wouldn't be an example -- tenuis is about phonation. This is a case where the wiki entry is in error, and the [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenuis) has it right. There are languages with [ʔʷ], [ʔʲ] although they may be described as "glottalized w" etc -- there is no distinction. Examples are Yurok, Klamath, Lushootseed.

Comment: Yawelmani also has glottalized y and w.  (No glottalized h, though I'm not sure that's impossible.)  Though its glottalized oral stops are ejective, y' and w' are just said with laryngealization.  I don't understand why y' and w' are the same as palatalized and labialized glottal stop.

Comment: (Somehow, I misparsed your comment, so I wiped out my response). Aspiration is the spreading of the glottis, and glottalization is the constriction of the glottis -- two contradictory states, which would have to be sequenced into two segments, not simultaneously into one, which is why glottalized h is impossible. The sameness of hʷ and w̥ (etc) deserves to be a separate question (suggestion...) with an answer that's longer that an enlarged tweet.

Comment: Yeah, but similar reasoning seems to lead to the conclusion that there can't be voiced h's or voiced aspirates, because h requires spreading the vocal cords while voicing requires approximating them.

Comment: Breathy voicing (voiced h and voiced aspiration) does not have appreciable vocal fold contact compared to modal voice, due to slight abduction of the vocal folds -- there is approximation but not glottal closure. Glottalization OTOH involves complete closure and only the anterior portion of the folds vibrate. If your reference point for glottal stricture is modal voice, breathy voice is minimally more open (compared to h, voiceless aspiration) and glottalization is minimally more closed (compared to complete closure as in ʔ or ejectives).

Comment: How would an aspirated glottal stop be contradictory? To my understanding, aspiration refers to the short period of voicelessness after the consonant's release, not the state of the glottis during the consonant's hold.

Comment: The glottis is spread during the closure of an aspirated consonant, but since there is no sound then, you can't hear anything until the consonant is released -- then there's that puff of air.

Comment: Since there is such a thing as voiced aspiration, aspiration doesn't just refer to VOT lag (also, there is VOT lag in ejectives, but ejectives aren't aspirated); anyhow, the cause of VOT lag is abducted vocal folds, which has to substantially overlap the stop closure (generally reaching the max. at the consonant's release).

Comment: Couldn't a "glottalized w" also describe a creaky-voiced [w]?

Comment: Yes, that's another term that is used.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://books.google.com/books?id=okRdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=%22aspirated+glottal+stop%22&source=bl&ots=QOb4OoKOm6&sig=Xi6T4Jat-pK8iOVcPcyWkm6haH0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBWoVChMImNfgituuxwIVjJmICh2l7whd#v=onepage&q=%22aspirated%20glottal%20stop%22&f=false) cites an article by Bessell (1992) arguing that Nlakapmxcin, a Northwest Coast language, has allophonically aspirated glottal stops.

Tinputz, a language of Papue New Guinea, is claimed [here](http://www-01.sil.org/pacific/png/abstract.asp?id=11161) to have allophonic word-final aspirated glottal stops.

(user6726 is of course correct that strictly speaking a glottal stop can't be aspirated, but that doesn't preclude that a language could possess a sound which might nevertheless be reasonably described as an aspirated glottal stop -- i.e. a glottal release immediately followed by aspiration, which I assume is what's happening here.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adyghe_language#Phonology), Adyghe has labialized glottal stops in phonemic distinction to plain ones, and the Abdzakh dialect of Adyghe and Hausa have palatalized glottal stops.

Comment: The Hausa example is a case in point in the fungibility of "glottalized y" ~ "palatalized glottal stop", since <'y> is traditionally called a glottalized *y*. http://aflang.humnet.ucla.edu/Hausa/Pronunciation/consonants.html

Comment: And I see no reason why it shouldn't be the same with Adyghe. So in the end it's a case of neither yes nor no but "depends on your definition".

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am a bit late, but there is an argument to be made that the underlying representation of Russian soft vowels involves /ʔʲ/. For example, according to the argument, the UR of ё (jo) is /ʔʲo/, and the UR of ю (ju) is /ʔʲu/.